# After uninstalling expired UFT from my pc, would i able to reinstall it with new registration?

Tags: functional-testing, hp-uft

I have installed trial[30 days]version of HP UFT 12.51. I have only 2 days in hand. After 2 days UFT will expire automatically and ask for license when I open it.

I have gone through some links and got only one solution : i.e format 'c' drive and reinstall UFT again with older setup.[Formatting c drive is not possible in my case].

**My question is that :-**

After uninstalling expired UFT, If i register again with new Id on hp site and download and install UFT again for 30 days, will it ask for license again after installing with new setup ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used up the free trial demo of UFT then uninstalling and re-installing will not give you another 30 days. In addition to the option you listed of formatting the `C:` drive there is one more option...

Pay for UFT.

Comment: As I asked if I register again[with new id] on HP site and download fresh setup then ? Will it ask for license again when I install fresh UFT?